# Change from "Session" to "StatelessSession" and I can fetch my Class complete

Tags: nhibernate, session, stateless

I use a stateless session and the follow HQL.

```
CreateQuery("select a from Address a")
```

My Address Class has many BankDetails but i can't access. If i use a normal session it works. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [fetch join](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins-forms) to pull in the bank details explicitly rather than relying on an implicit load when you first access the `BankDetails` property:

```
CreateQuery("select a from Address a inner join fetch a.BankDetails")
```

Comment: Thank's Kent. Is there a generally option to pull all data?

Comment: You can add lazy="false" in your mapping to ensure that certain collections are always loaded eagerly, but beware of the performance implications.

Comment: The result of the query is not unique. It's the same count like the Bankdetails. What can i do?